# link group java is broken (can't install java in Ubuntu with WSL2)

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, java, jdk

I'm new to using Linux via WSL2 and I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkYFWigwpbM) to install java on Ubuntu

Ubuntu is up-to-date

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64 and installing JDK 17

I am getting this error when executing this-

```
nick@prab:/usr/lib/jvm$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17-oracle-x64/bin/java 1
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17-oracle-x64/bin/java because link group java is broken
```

What does it mean "link group java is broken" ??

Please help me troubleshoot this.